# React & Typescript: Intersection type with Higher Order Control & Generic Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I'm getting this error when I use a generic type with this Higher Order
Control in React & TypeScript (using @types/react 15.0.27):

```
TS2322:Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & 
IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<ITypeComponentProps, ComponentState>> & ...'.
     Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<ITypeComponentProps>'.
     Property 'data' is missing in type '{}'.
```

I expected my `withTestData` function to return a control of type `React.ComponentClass<ITestComponentProps>` (i.e. with empty props), but it is telling me that I need to pass `data` in props.  However, it works as expected when when I replace the generic type `ITypeTestProps<TData>`
below with the non-generic type `ITypeTestProps`, and TData with a type like `string`.

`withTestData` looks kind of mind-bending, but it does something fairly straightforward---it takes a component that expects props of type `P & ITypeTestProps<TData>` and
wraps it in a component that expects props of type `P`.  In this test case, `P` is `ITestComponentProps`.

Here's the version with the error:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {mount} from "enzyme";

interface ITestComponentProps {}

type HOC<PWrapped, PHoc> = React.ComponentClass<PWrapped & PHoc> | 
    React.SFC<PWrapped & PHoc>;

export interface ITypeTestProps<TData> {
    data: TData;
}

export function withTestData<P, S, TData>(Component: HOC<P, 
    ITypeTestProps<TData>>, data: TData):
    React.ComponentClass<P> {

    class C extends React.Component<P & ITypeTestProps<TData>, S> {

        public render(): JSX.Element {
            return (
                <Component data={data} {...this.props as any} />
            );
        }
    }
    return C;
}

type ITypeComponentProps = ITestComponentProps & ITypeTestProps<String>;

class TestComponent extends React.Component<ITypeComponentProps, {}> {
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (<div>Hello, {this.props.data}</div>);
    }
}

describe("withTestData()", () => {

    it("wraps a component", () => {
        const data: string = "World";
        const WrappedTestComponent = withTestData(TestComponent, data);
        // The type mismatch occurs here:
        const wrapper = mount(<WrappedTestComponent />);
        expect(wrapper.text()).toContain(`Hello, ${data}`);
    });

});
```

I can work around it by casting the control like this, but I'd like to eliminate the cast:

```js
const WrappedTestComponent = withTestData(TestComponent, data) as 
    React.ComponentClass<ITestComponentProps>
```

**EDIT**

Here's a version that works as I expected---it removes "data" from the generated interface.  The only difference is that the type is not generic.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {mount} from "enzyme";

interface ITestComponentProps {}

type HOC<PWrapped, PHoc> = React.ComponentClass<PWrapped & PHoc> |
    React.SFC<PWrapped & PHoc>;

export interface ITypeTestProps {
    data: string;
}

export function withTestData<P, S, TData>(Component: HOC<P, ITypeTestProps>, data: TData):
    React.ComponentClass<P> {

    class C extends React.Component<P & ITypeTestProps, S> {

        public render(): JSX.Element {
            return (
                <Component data={data} {...this.props as any} />
            );
        }
    }
    return C;
}

type ITypeComponentProps = ITestComponentProps & ITypeTestProps;

class TestComponent extends React.Component<ITypeComponentProps, {}> {
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (<div>Hello, {this.props.data}</div>);
    }
}

describe("withTestData()", () => {

    it("wraps a component", () => {
        const data: string = "World";
        const WrappedTestComponent = withTestData(TestComponent, data);
        // The type mismatch occurs here:
        const wrapper = mount(<WrappedTestComponent />);
        expect(wrapper.text()).toContain(`Hello, ${data}`);
    });

});
```

To run this example from zero:

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app
$ create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
$ cd my-app/
$ npm install @types/react@15.0.27 enzyme --dev
```

Copy the above code into a file `src/demo.test.tsx`

```
$ npm test
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is correctly warns that you have missed to provide value for the mandatory property of the `ITypeTestProps` interface.

Therefore in order to get rid of the problem (and if it is ok for your business logic not to have one) you can declare `data` as optional property in the `ITypeTestProps` interface:

```
export interface ITypeTestProps<TData> {
    data?: TData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the error that it's returning, but I believe it is being reported incorrectly---I added another example to clarify the difference.

Comment: Hmmm. Thats quite weird. As a workaround though you can make your `withTestData` to return `React.ComponentClass<P & ITypeTestProps>` this way your will get correct error as expected